# How does Flink allocate DAG nodes to different task slots?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Reading the Flink tutorial example, I am wondering how Flink assign DAG nodes to different task slots in a Flink cluster. Any pointer will be greatly appreciated.

```
    val windowCounts = text
        .flatMap { w => w.split("\\s") }
        .map { w => WordWithCount(w, 1) }
        .keyBy("word")
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(1))
        .sum("count")
```

Answer (score 1):

What Flink tries to do when scheduling a DAG is first of all it tries to chain as many operators as possible. Chains are usually broken if an operator has multiple inputs or at shuffles. Chains will be executed in a single `Task` on the `TaskManager` and don't involve any serialization between the chained operators.

After having transformed the input DAG into `Tasks`, Flink will parallelize the DAG by splitting the `Tasks` into sub tasks. A sub task receives and processes a partition of the parent Task's input.

Next Flink will allocate for each sub task a slot. If slot sharing is enabled for the operators (which is the default), then sub tasks from different operators can be scheduled to the same `Slot`. This not only allows to easier reason about the required resources but gives also better resource utilization. Each sub task is executed by a separate thread.

You can find more information about Flink's scheduling [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/internals/job_scheduling.html).